# The word "doooooooor" often girlishly said, what is the actual spelling?

Tags: american-english

> Boy: May I know you're name please?
>   Girl: I'm not telling, doooooor!

I know I'm spelling it like a 'door' but that's actually how it sounds. Is it an English word and what's the right spelling.

Comment: Are you transcribing this in a rhotic or non-rhotic accent?

Comment: I think rhotic accent. Its like a slang or somewhat. But i hear most girls say either 'dooor' or 'daaaaaaar' i cant actually figure how to spell it to get your understanding of this word in question.

Comment: I googled it and found that in most cases, it's actually *door* spoken with a lot of stress (in frustration). Maybe, the girl wants to show/point at door telling him to go away?

Comment: @MaulikV No; I think it's *dhurrrr* or *durrr* with as many extra r's added for emphasis. It's used *everywhere* but I have no idea what it means or if it even means anything. My bet is that it's an interjection, a filler ?word, a corruption of *duh*, or all of the above.

Comment: @helix Yes, I'm pretty sure that's it. (It's not pronounced "door" in my accent; it rhymes with "burr".) It's an expression that the other person has said something stupid or asked an obvious question.

Comment: I think the common spelling for this sound is *Duh!*, sometimes *Doh!*.

Comment: To be sure, check out this video. See if it's the same sound: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDbHwz6JGzo

Comment: In its usual expression, it is intended to mean 'not my business' or 'i don't care'. Only God knows where such word is borrowed from.

Comment: What helix and starsplusplus said. In Australia, we would spell it derr (with extra 'r's as needed).  I heard it long before 'duh!' and 'D'oh!' is from the Simpsons.  The meaning we give it, as used in the example sentence is more 'well obviously, you idiot'.  Now, I'm off to google rhotic.

Comment: Durrrrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: There's also 'doy'

Comment: "You are name"? huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The actual spelling of "doooooor" is "duh".

According to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/35194/14157) to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35188/origin-of-the-word-duh):

According to Merriam Webster, *duh* is an interjection which has two [meanings](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duh):

> 1. used to express actual or feigned ignorance or stupidity
> 2. used derisively to indicate that something just stated is all too obvious or self-evident

Apparently this first appeared in 1966 (per Merriam Webster). If you look at Google NGrams, "duh" has appeared even in the 1800s but a quick look at the results shows that in the early cases "duh" was used mostly as a syllable in a foreign language or as a form of "the". You can see that there is an increase over time, regardless, after 1960.

[image]

The etymology of the interjection is, as you suggested, onomatopoeic in origin. One site, Think-Ink, devotes an entire [page](http://www.think-ink.net/doh/meaning.htm) to the discussion of the word. One thing they mention is an etymology, from the American Heritage Dictionary:

> Imitative of the utterance attributed to slow-witted people.